# Spark 2.0 implicit encoder, deal with missing column when type is Option[Seq[String]] (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm having some trouble encoding data when some columns that are of type Option[Seq[String]] are missing from our data source. Ideally I would like the missing column data to be filled with `None`.

Scenario:

We have some parquet files that we are reading in that have *column1* but not *column2*.

We load the data in from these parquet files into a `Dataset`, and cast it as `MyType`.

```
case class MyType(column1: Option[String], column2: Option[Seq[String]])

sqlContext.read.parquet("dataSource.parquet").as[MyType]
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`column2`' given input columns: [column1];

Is there a way to create the Dataset with column2 data as `None`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In simple cases you can provide an initial schema which is a superset of expected schemas. For example in your case:

```scala
val schema = Seq[MyType]().toDF.schema

Seq("a", "b", "c").map(Option(_))
  .toDF("column1")
  .write.parquet("/tmp/column1only")

val df = spark.read.schema(schema).parquet("/tmp/column1only").as[MyType]
df.show
```

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|      a|   null|
|      b|   null|
|      c|   null|
+-------+-------+
```

```scala
df.first
```

```
MyType = MyType(Some(a),None)
```

This approach can be **a little bit fragile** so in general you should rather use SQL literals to fill the blanks:

```scala
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/column1only")
  // or ArrayType(StringType)
  .withColumn("column2", lit(null).cast("array<string>"))
  .as[MyType]
  .first
```

```
MyType = MyType(Some(a),None)
```

Comment: How would this situation be handled if a column (or a number of columns) is optionally missing (a column may or may not be present)? Saw you want to conform data from a KV map to a case class based on the same key to value mapping?

Comment: @OmkarNeogi there is one solution here which create an implicit method on DF which will check for missing fields then fill those with null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886211/spark-default-null-columns-dataset

Answer (score 0):

Since spark 3.1, you can make use of the `allowMissingColumns` parameter for [`Dataset#unionByName`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#unionByName(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D,allowMissingColumns:Boolean):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BT%5D) to introduce missing columns:

```scala
spark.read.parquet("dataSource.parquet")
  // Add extra column by joining with empty dataframe using the expected schema
  .unionByName(spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], schema), true)
  // Extra check to see if schema really matches
  .as(RowEncoder.apply(schema))
```