# Kafka spark streaming dynamic schema

Tags: apache-spark, dynamic, apache-kafka

I'm strangling Kafka spark streaming with dynamic schema.
I"m consuming from Kafka (KafkaUtils.createDirectStream)  each message /JSON field can be nested, each field can appear in some messages and sometimes not.

The only thing I found is to do:
[Spark 2.0 implicit encoder, deal with missing column when type is Option[Seq[String]] (scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454144/spark-2-0-implicit-encoder-deal-with-missing-column-when-type-is-optionseqstr)

case  class  MyTyp(column1: Option[Any], column2: Option[Any]....)
This will cover,im not sure, fields that may appear, and nested Fileds.

Any approval/other Ideas/general help will be appreciated ...

Comment: Pretty sure you can use  Map type for the dynamic json fields/columns. I haven't tried this myself though.

Answer (score 1):

After long integration and trails, two ways to solve non schema Kafka consuming: 1) Throw "editing/validation" each message with "lambda" function .not my favorite. 2) Spark: on each micro batch obtain flatten schema and intersect needed columns. use spark SQL to query the frame for needed data. That worked for me.